# The super.initState() method isn't working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a meals app & I'm trying to add a feature that will filter out the meals ( select which ones are visible. ) The filters work perfectly but the problem comes when I hit the back button & return to the screen, the filters won't save. With initState() I should be able to save the values, & return back to the screen with all the filters in tack. It's quite a bit of code, so I'll try to simplify it as much as possible.

***filters.dart***:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum Filter { glutenFree, lactoseFree, vegetarian, vegan }

class FiltersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FiltersScreen({super.key, required this.currentFilters});

  // This is the variable the filters will be save in
  final Map<Filter, bool> currentFilters;

  @override
  State<FiltersScreen> createState() {
    return _FiltersScreenState();
  }
}

class _FiltersScreenState extends State<FiltersScreen> {
  var _glutenFreeFilterSet = false;
  var _lactoseFreeFilterSet = false;
  var _vegetarianFilterSet = false;
  var _veganFilterSet = false;

  // This is supposed to set the old filter values to the new ones when you tap the button
  @override
  void initialize() {
    super.initState();
    _glutenFreeFilterSet = widget.currentFilters[Filter.glutenFree]!;
    _lactoseFreeFilterSet = widget.currentFilters[Filter.lactoseFree]!;
    _vegetarianFilterSet = widget.currentFilters[Filter.vegetarian]!;
    _veganFilterSet = widget.currentFilters[Filter.vegan]!;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Your Filters'),
      ),
      body: PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
          if (didPop) return;
          Navigator.of(context).pop({
            Filter.glutenFree: _glutenFreeFilterSet,
            Filter.lactoseFree: _lactoseFreeFilterSet,
            Filter.vegetarian: _vegetarianFilterSet,
            Filter.vegan: _veganFilterSet,
          });
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SwitchListTile(
              value: _glutenFreeFilterSet,
              onChanged: (isChecked) {
                setState(() {
                  _glutenFreeFilterSet = isChecked;
                });
              },
              title: Text(
                'Gluten-Free',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                    ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                'only show the Gluten-Free category',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium!.copyWith(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                    ),
              ),
              activeColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 32,
                right: 22,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Since most of the code works I think you just have to pay attention to the code that has comments above them.

Tabs.dart - *I removed most of the code in this file*

```
class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabsScreen({super.key});

  void _setScreen(String identifier) async {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    if (identifier == "filters") {
      final result = await Navigator.of(context).push<Map<Filter, bool>>(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (ctx) => FiltersScreen(
            // This also sets the filters form the tabs screen
            currentFilters: _selectedFilters,
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant but I also this message. The problem is when I remove the @override the code still doesnt work.

[image]

Comment: rename `void initialize` to `void initState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the Correct Method:

Ensure you're using initState() instead of initialize(): It's the correct method to perform initialization tasks within a State object.
replace:

```dart
void initialize() {
```

with

```dart
void initState() {
```